# OK to power down server every day?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, boot

If I may give a little background before my question. I'm winding down my web developmet business so have moved out of the office to WFH. I might just do some work maybe one or two days a week.

Have a server running FreeBSD Unix. While in the office it was on 24/7, but with WFH and the energy costs here in Europe, I can't justify leaving it on all the time.

Is there any issues turning on and off a server just like a regular desktop PC? Is the HDD in any way different to a desktop one in that if should not go through as many on/off cycles?

It's a Dell PowerEdge T110 II purchased in 2015. I can't find the exact spec from the service tag, just found that is supports up to four 3.5-inch, cabled SAS or SATA internal drives. They are not solid state.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that server is used for local development and not to actually host your web sites on the Internet. If so, you can treat it as a regular pc and turn it on/off per your needs.
The reason servers are usually on 24/7 is because so they can serve its content to whoever requests it at any time, if you are the sole accessor, the server only needs to be on whenn you want it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, exactly as you say, a local dev server.

Comment: Great, then feel free to turn it on and off how you see fit. There should be absolutely no problem there.